# IOS: How to create a destroy effect animation on a uiview

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, quartz-graphics, effect

I want to create an effect to destroy a view after it is stretched.

It could be anything from pop like a baloon, expode, break into shards, something like that, even simply split by half and then i will fade out the pieces. But I haven't found anything similar in quartz or have much idea on how to do it.

Each view is different from the other, but if there is no other way I guess that I will create a background of several pieces that can be animated individually.

Comment: Here are some cools ones: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hmgltransitions though nothing like a balloon or shards

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no built-in functionality for this kind of thing, but the following might point you in the right direction.  I don't have the time to go into explicit detail, but I felt like you might benefit from some general guidelines, at least until someone else can provide sample code or a different approach.

Sounds like you want to implement a simple particle generator, render your view to an image, and feed that image into the generator to create the particles, then animate them according to the desired effect.

There might be existing third party libraries to do this (And I would search around before implementing something like this), otherwise there are a few approaches you can take, I'll just give the basic idea:

The generator takes the image and makes some sub-images in the shape of your particle (like shards).  You'll need an algorithm to figure out the shapes and sizes, then you can either use CAShapeLayer masks on an image or actually render smaller images (Choose whatever requires less duplicate stored image data in memory, IE, if using one image object as the source for multiple CALayers/UIImageViews with masks is optimized to only copy the pixels it needs to the screen and does not actually duplicate the data, then that might be your best option.  You can determine that behavior by searching around or as a last resort writing code).

Once you have your collection of views / layers, you can use another algorithm to calculate new sizes/positions/rotations for a given effect, and just use the standard animation api to move the contents of your collection provided by the algorithm.  Again, the implementation will depend on potential optimizations you might need to make.  Using CALayer directly will have better performance than a collection of UIImageViews.